# What is the standard commit process for Hg?

Tags: mercurial

Is it

1. pull
2. update
3. merge
4. commit
5. push

? Or can you do the commit first?

I don't like the idea of pulling and merging without having a version of my local code backed up somewhere in case the merge explodes, but presumably you have to do the merge before you can do a push, because you can't have conflicts in the central repo. Not quite understanding this whole process yet; used to my nice simple SVN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend to always commit before pulling in changes to your working directory, unless you are 100% sure that your changes and the changes to be merged into your working directory will not conflict.

If you do an updating pull (`hg pull; hg update`, or shorter `hg -u pull`) and have any outstanding non-committed changes, any changes coming from outside will be combined with your changes. When conflicts happen, it might be difficult to decide how the merge result should look like, because you can't easily distinguish between your changes and the changes merged in.

When you did commit first, it is much easier to decide how the merge result should look like, because you can always look at both parents of the merge.
So, in effect it is:

1. `hg commit`
2. `hg pull -u` (if no merge necessary, go to 5)
3. `hg merge`
4. `hg commit`
5. `hg push`

**Update:** As Martin Geisler has pointed out, it is possible to get at the "original" changed version of a file using:

```
hg resolve --unmark the-file
hg resolve --tool internal:local the-file
```

or for all files at the same time:

```
hg resolve --unmark --all
hg resolve --tool internal:local -all
```

Still, I find the "commit first" system nicer. At the end, it is personal preference...

Comment: It's incorrect that you cannot abort the update. You can use `hg resolve` afterwards to get your old files back. You're not the only one surprised by this, see this recent thread: http://markmail.org/message/izeibc7ixlwehwuf

Comment: @MartinGeisler Can this be done for all conflicted files at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can use `hg resolve --all --tool internal:local` to get back all the original files. You'll still need to `hg update` back before you have completely undone the first `hg update`. All in all, I'll say that it's easier and safer to commit before you update, but if you don't, then we still have your back :-)

Comment: By #2 do you mean `hg -u pull` ("updating pull")? Otherwise, you don't have an update in there. Or maybe I don't understand what the difference between "pull" and "update" are in this context. I thought a "pull" was essentially downloading the code from the central repo, and "update" was to update your local codebase.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you're right, I'll change that. Still, when changes have to be merged in, the update will just state that you'll have to use merge instead.

Comment: @danielkullmann: So a "merge" basically does an update *and* merge then?

Comment: @Mark No, a merge just merges, and in the process of the merge, "remote" changes are integrated with your changes. Update and merge are really two different concepts. An update just adds existing changesets on top of your tip changeset; no conflicts can arise, because you have not added anything yourself. A merge has to integrate changes from two parent changesets, and will result (after the commit) in a new changeset that contains all changes from the "remote" head.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know as there's a standard per se, but one of the ideas behind Mercurial is that you can commit as often as you like since it goes to your local repository. So you can commit to your heart's content as much as you like before you pull updates.

I tend not to commit very often, saving up for when I'm preparing to push, but that's me. I can see the utility of committing early and often. I do pull updates frequently as I work to cut down on merge fun.

One other thing I do is to keep a parallel clone of my working repo (cloned from the same repository as my working repo, not cloned from my working repo) so that I can check the original state of a file easily, and if need-be check in an out-of-band emergency fix or what-have-you without complicating my current change set.

Comment: So.... presumably then, I could do the commit first if I wanted to, but then I suspect I'd have to commit a 2nd time if there's a merge, but when I go to push them....will the wind up under one "changeset"?

Comment: You have to commit the merge separately regardless. If all your files are committed, you can then merge, and then you must commit the merge. If your changes are not committed, you're required to commit them before you *can* merge, and then you must commit the merge. I believe they all become part of one changeset, called a merge changeset (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: The first half I don’t think is good practice so I can’t really upvote the answer (sorry :)), but the part about a parallel clone for out of band fixes is good advice!

Answer (score 3):

1. Do edits
2. Commit
3. Goto 1 until satisfied
4. Pull
5. Merge & commit
6. Push if you want to.

Definitely commit before trying to do something complex like a merge. I don't think mercurial will allow you to merge before committing, but even if it did, what if the merge goes wrong. You have no pre-merge revision to go back to.

Commit early, commit often.

If you don't, you are missing out on a huge benefit of a DVCS.

Answer (score 2):

> but presumably you have to do the merge before you can do a push, because you can't have conflicts in the central repo

Wrong statement and poor understanding of distributed workflow and parallel development.

1. You *can* merge heads before push, but **not have or must**. Push can put any data to repo, if it needed and intended to be so

   > By default, push will not allow creation of new heads at the destination,
   >   since multiple heads would make it unclear which head to use. In this
   >   situation, it is recommended to pull and merge before pushing.

(NB: "**recommended** to pull and merge before" statement)

You can use commit-pull-merge, stash-pull-unstash-merge, perform fetch with *modified WC* and merge on the fly, don't merge heads at all or sporadically and `push --force` with +1 heads - **there are not common rule for everybody**. And any and every such workflow doesn't produce "conflicts in the central repo", but only **different DAG**.

Each point of divergence, which appear in case of existing *your* and *other* changeset  from commmon parent in your (or even central) repo is a point of starting anonymous branches in Hg, which (technically) are absolutely legal, applicable and usual way. How they handled is defined by policy and agreement between developers, PM, QA-team and others

I, personally, prefer finish my task (in one or more amount of commits), after it pull and *maybe merge*, when it approved by development-policy

[image: Part of repo]

Comment: You're right that I don't fully understand it, that's why I'm asking. You're saying that I can do a push without first doing a merge, but it will create a new head? I don't think I really understand how to read that graph either. I get that each of those lines is a different branch, and I'd imagine that when they connect again is a merge, but there's merges in there where the lines don't collapse.

Comment: And I realize that not everyone is following the same process, otherwise they wouldn't give us so much flexibility, but I suspect certain processes are more common. Like, it wouldn't be customary to create a new head every time you push and never merge, for example. I suspect the only time you'd want to do that is if you need to do a quick fix, or you're developing conflicting features and you want to role them out/merge them separately, but that isn't the norm.

Comment: yes, push without merge will create additional head. You **can** use this style. My graph is easy readable - after 33 revision before 40 my repo had 2 heads and after 43 *can have* in clone, but I merge immediatelly. And all time repository *just works*

Comment: My question was regarding what happens between 39 and 40? It says a merge is performed but there's still 2 branches if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: between 39 and 40 I done merge of two heads from default branch (39 & 35) and got one head in one branch